# Book about using Mathematica in real world engineering projects

Tags: reference-request, engineering

So far I've abused *Mathematica* by only using it as a notebook. That's a big waste since I've bought a student-life time *Mathematica* 9 / SystemModeler license. My problem is that I'm not inspired to use *Mathematica* in my projects because I've never seen examples of people using Mathematica in their workflow when working on new projects.

There are several tutorials on how to use a particular function, how to solve this kind of mathematical problem and more generally how to program with *Mathematica*. But that's not what I'm after. I need examples of various real world engineering projects that has been developped from end to end using *Mathematica*. Examples of workflows, this kind of books. Most of the books are *Mathematica* references: if you want to calculate this, do it like that, if you want to program this, do it like that, but it's not really inspiring.

This [book would have been perfect](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2673/) however I'm not sure it's a good idea to read it since it's quite old (1994) and relies on *Mathematica* 2. I'm looking for a book having the exact same approach but that uses a more recent version of *Mathematica*. I enjoy it because it presents several complex real-world engineering projects completed using *Mathematica*.

Do you know a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure wether it is what you need.

In **Wolfram Research** sites http://www.wolfram.com/books/

[image]

I found a book called `An Engineer's Guide to Mathematica Paperback` – May 5, 2014
by Edward B. Magrab  (Author)

And you can buy a printed book in Amazon.

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1118821262/wolframresearch-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118821262)

Lastly, seeing your question:

> My problem is that I'm not inspired to use Mathematica in my projects because I've never seen examples of people using Mathematica in their workflow when working on new projects.

I have applied *Mathematica* to my ***undergraduate paper***: `"The simulation of the  kinematics and dynamics of SCARA robot"` successfuly. The main results I have submitted to `Wolfram Demonstration`.

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Shutao%20Tang

Comment: Thank you, it should do the trick ! I hope the examples it contains are elaborated and are not too much trivial.

Comment: @Joeyy, You are welcome. I am very happy to learn knowledge and `English` in StackExchange(although my english is poor).