# What is a good book to learn mathematics with Mathematica?

Tags: programming, education

I'd like to review first-year college math, and above, while learning Mathematica alongside it. All the books I've looked at that claim to teach some version of math with Mathematica go though two or three dizzying chapters of theory before a single line of code. I learn by doing, and even creating my own problems. I want a book that gets me coding higher math right from the start. I've looked around and just  haven't seen a book like that from the sample chapters.f

Comment: [An elementary introduction to the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/?source=nav), or [Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction](https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/), or Wolfram's [A New Kind of Science](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/) are examples. See also [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/27951).

Comment: I think this could be a duplicate of  [What Mathematica book to buy?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-mathematica-book-to-buy). See also: [Book about using Mathematica in real world engineering projects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59983/27951).

Comment: Seconding MarcoB's comments. I wish I had these as a first-year college math student. Particularly keen on Shifrin's  Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction. But if you're starting out then an elementary intro to the Wolfram language is a great starter.

Comment: There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: In addition to what others already suggested, I would recommend "Mathematica Navigator" by Ruskeepaa. There are also books "Mathematica in action" by Stan Wagon and "The Student's Introduction to Mathematica" by Bruce Torrence, the latter probably somewhat more elementary. Finally, while I have not read the recent books "Analysis with Mathematica" (2 volumes) by Galina Filipuk and Andrzej Kozlowski, I do know the authors and would certainly expect those books to be pretty good.  I am sure I missed quite a few good titles, but those I mentioned are at least the ones I've been familiar with.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Analysis with Mathematica has a third volume, devoted to differential geometry, differential equations, and special functions.

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thanks for the info, I did not know that.

Comment: I've taken a course at Univ. California, Irvine, where we used Mathematica for everything. It was a Physics course. The book used is  https://mathematica-handbook.com/  and it is all about using Mathematica for physics. All hands on.  I bought the book and I think it is great.  You can see the table of content [here](http://www.mathematicahandbook.com/videos/TOCNarrow.html)